# webscrapping by Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I tried to extract data from below site but I don't know how to put the xpath in the loop "for", because the loop needs to be convert xpath to str, could you do me a favor and help me:

Site: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/imp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-01-01&r9=2022-05-01

```
    from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/71-607-x2021004-eng.htm')
time.sleep(2)
# finding the button using ID
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cimt_import"]/p[1]/a')
# clicking on the button
button.click()
time.sleep(2)
# finding the button using ID
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="topic3s"]')
# clicking on the button
button.click()
time.sleep(2)
# finding the start year:2022 from scroll
element_drop_down_startYear = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fromYear"]/option[1]')
element_drop_down_startYear.click()
# finding the start month from:January scroll
element_drop_down_startMonth = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fromMonth"]/option[1]')
element_drop_down_startMonth.click()
# finding the End year from scroll
element_drop_down_endYear = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="toYear"]/option[1]')
element_drop_down_endYear.click()
# finding the End month from scroll
element_drop_down_endmonth = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="toMonth"]/option[5]')
element_drop_down_endmonth.click()
# finding the specific Chapter
element_drop_down_specificChapter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_hs"]/option[1]')
element_drop_down_specificChapter.click()
time.sleep(1)
# finding the specific Commodity from the list
element_drop_down_specific_commodity = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_hs"]/option[2]')
element_drop_down_specific_commodity.click()
# finding the specific Commodity from the list
element_drop_down_specific_button= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/p[2]/button')
element_drop_down_specific_button.click()



#--------------------------------------------------------------------   

 cel = 1
 for cel in rane(25):
    x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a')
    print(x)

    print("//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["+ cel +"]/td[4]")
    print("//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["+ cel +"]/td[7]")
    print("//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["+ cel +"]/td[8]/abbr")


time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: please post minimal reproducible example, exactly at which part are you getting error

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the element before printing it, otherwise you're printing a string. I think what you want to do is in each iteration of the for loop print those selectors? if so find the elements like so, then print them.

```
 for i in range(25):
    x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a')
    print(x)

    element_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[4]')
    element_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[7]')
    element_3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[8]/abbr')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the Network tab, you can see that webpage is pulling the table data from
https://www150.statcan.gc.ca//t1/cimt/rest/getReport/(1)/0/0/12/0/150000/1/0/2022-01-01/2022-05-01

Scrape that json page instead:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www150.statcan.gc.ca//t1/cimt/rest/getReport/(1)/0/0/12/0/150000/1/0/2022-01-01/2022-05-01')
print(r.json())
```